# How to check if file contains strings, which will double repeat sign?

Tags: c#, file, openfiledialog

I would like to check if file containing some strings, separated with `#` contains double repeat sign. Example:
I have a file like this:

```
1234#224859#123567
```

I am reading this file and putting strings separated with `#` it into array. 
I would like to find which strings have a digit repeated next to each other (in this case `224859`) and return position of first digit that repeats in this string?

This is what I have so far:

```
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    OpenFileDialog openFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        int size = -1;
        DialogResult dr = openFile1.ShowDialog();
        string file = openFile1.FileName;
        try
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
            size = text.Length;
            string temp = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                if (text[i] != '#')
                {
                    temp += text[i].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    list.Add(temp);
                    temp = "";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
        }
        string all_values = "";
        foreach (Object obj in list)
        {
            all_values += obj.ToString() + " => ";

            Console.WriteLine(" => ", obj);
        }
        textBox1.Text = (all_values);
```

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I do not know what you want to do. "I would like to find which strings holds double repeat sign (in this case 224859)" Does this mean strings that have any double character?

Comment: Some sample input/output would be really good here. Seems like a good use case for String.Split() but its hard to tell without more info.

Comment: What I mean is exactly which number, holds 2 same digits next to each other! Hope now it's clear :D

Comment: You need only `22` or `224859`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I believe he needs `0`, the index of the repeat.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect what you said in the comments. Can you verify this is correct?

Comment: @clcto Exactly I need 0, index of the repeat!

Comment: just one more question, if the string was 12234#224859#12334 would the output be {1, 0, 2} ?

Comment: What is the expected output for the string you have?  Is it a `List<int>` that looks something like: `{null, 0, null}`?  What if you have `11#4322#43#155`?  Should the output be something like `{0, 2, null, 1}`?

Comment: Yes, it would be {1, 0, 2} :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more procedural approach than Sriram's, but the main benefit is remembering your results in order to use them later in your program.

Basically, the string is split based on the `#` delimiter, which returns a `string[]` which holds each number inside.  Then, for each string you iterate through the characters and check to see if the current character at `i` matches the next character at `i + 1`.  If so, the earliest appearance of a duplicate digit is at `i`, so `i` is remembered and we break out of the loop that processes `char`s.

Since `int` is a non-nullable type, I decided to use `-1` to indicate that a match was not found in a string.

```
Dictionary<string, int> results = new Dictionary<string, int>();
string text = "1234#224859#123567#11#4322#43#155";
string[] list = text.Split('#');
foreach (string s in list)
{
    int tempResult = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if(s.ElementAt(i) == s.ElementAt(i + 1))
        {
            tempResult = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    results.Add(s, tempResult);
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in results) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + ": " + pair.Value);
}
```

Output:

> 1234: -1
>
> 224859: 0
>
> 123567: -1
>
> 11: 0
>
> 4322: 2
>
> 43: -1
>
> 155: 1

Comment: I like your solution better than mine.  The Dictionary and ElementAt are quite elegant, Ryan.

Answer (score 3):

This regex should do the trick.

```
var subject = "1234#224859#123567";
foreach(var item in subject.Split('#'))
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"(?<grp>\d)\k<grp>");
    var match =regex.Match(item);
    if(match.Success)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Index : {0}, Item:{1}", match.Index, item);
        //prints Index : 0, Item:224859
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this do what you are looking for?

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(file);

string[] list = text.Split(new char[] { '#' });
```

Then, after you have the strings separated:

```
        foreach (string s in list)
        {
            int pos = HasDoubleCharacter(s);
            if (pos > -1)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }

    private static int HasDoubleCharacter(string text)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        char[] c3 = text.ToCharArray();
        char lastChar = (char)0;
        foreach (char c in c3)
        {
            if (lastChar == c)
                return pos;
            lastChar = c;
            pos++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Or are you just looking for the list of positions of all doubles in the original text.  If so (and you don't need to act on the various strings separately, you might try this:

```
    private static List<int> FindAllDoublePositions(string text)
    {
        List<int> positions = new List<int>();
        char[] ca = text.ToCharArray();
        char lastChar = (char)0;
        for (int pos = 0; pos < ca.Length; pos++)
        {
            if (Char.IsNumber(ca[pos]) && lastChar == ca[pos])
                positions.Add(pos);
            lastChar = ca[pos];
        }
        return positions;
    }
```

Comment: Apparently not (though this is what I thought initially as well)

Comment: OK, I hadn't yet gotten the rest of what he was trying to do.  This ought to do it.  Not as elegant as using Regex, but I'm a big fan of simple and understandable.

Comment: Also, from the example it looks as if all the characters in the file are numbers, but if you are anticipating non-digits just add this test:  if (Char.IsNumber(c) && lastChar == c)

Comment: You also might think about how to handle non-standard cases.  What if you have two score marks together? (123#345##4556).  And how do you want to handle "triples"?  If a string is #12333456" do you only want to know about the first position (2) or do you see two doubles (2,3)?

Answer (score 0):

here's another Regex that works

```
      int indexof = -1;
        String input = "3492883#32280948093284#990303294";
        string[] numbers = input.Split('#');
        foreach(string n in numbers)
        {
            Match m=Regex.Match(n, @"(\d)\1+");
            if (m.Success)
            {
                indexof = m.Index;
            }

        }
```

Comment: That's basically same, not another regex. I've used named group where as you used index that's the difference.

Answer (score -1):

If your looking for a specific string pattern, Regex is most likely to be your best friend :

```
string text = "1234#224859#123567asdashjehqwjk4234#244859#123567asdhajksdhqjkw1434#244859#123567";

var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"\d{4}#(?<Value>\d{6})#\d{4}");
var allValues = "";

foreach (Match result in results)
{
    allValues = result.Groups["Value"].Value + " => ";
    Console.WriteLine(" => ", result.Value);
}
```